# Reading parameters in an SDL Tridion 2011 publish dialog extension

Tags: tridion

I've built a GUI extension to 'inject' my own JavaScript into the SDL Tridion 2011 publish dialog (as explained in this post and comment: http://albertromkes.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/)

I see in SDL Tridion's publish dialog (publish.js) that the publish dialog takes some parameters (not on the URL), these are passed in. For example:

```
var p = this.properties;
if (p.params && p.params.items && p.params.items.length > 0)
```

So in my JavaScript I'd like to get hold of the properties.params.items but I cannot seem to get hold of it.

My JavaScript code is inserted 'after' the publish view has loaded:

```
<cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.Publish">
  <cfg:insertafter>Extensions.Resources</cfg:insertafter>
</cfg:extension>
```

And in my JavaScript (and in Firebug Console) I've tried to obtain the value using `$display.getView().properties`, but this returns a `null` object.

I've been using Firebug to look around the `window`, `$display` and various other objects, but cannot see a way to get to the `params` object.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", itemsForPublish);

function itemsForPublish() {

    var p = $display.getView().properties;
    var items = p.params.items || [];

    alert(items);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
function itemsForPublish() {
    alert(window.dialogArguments.items);
}
```

In the 'Publishing.js' (and in 'Publish.js') you can see that the items to publish are send to the Popups' dialogArguments.

Comment: Thanks Albert, that worked.   I had tried this code, but i was refreshing the publish dialog to check the changes.   When doing this the params object is null.  So it's definitely worth noting the publish dialog should be closed / opened each time to check.